# Group by and count of a pandas dataframe column

Tags: pandas, group-by, count

I have a pandas dataframe where I am trying to group a column and get the unique values of another column.

```
  id    name   
  a-1   sfdad
  a-1   sfdad
  a-1   oiuoi
  a-2   oqrwq
  a-2   oqrwq
  a-2   ljlsg
  a-2   uoire
```

I do the group by using:

```
  df = df.groupby('id')['name'].agg(['unique'])
  df = df.reset_index()
```

and then when i do the count of column "unique" using the below statement, it does not align with the results of df['unique']. Length of df['unique'] and the below statement seems to be different.

```
 df.groupby('id')['name'].nunique()
```

Result

```
id   unique                count
a-1  [sfdad,oiuoi]         2
a-2  [oqrwq,ljlsg,uoire]   3
```

Comment: It seems to work as expected. What is different? what do you get and what do you expect?

Comment: @Tranbi: length of "unique" and the column count seem not to align

Comment: They do look align to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute several things at once with `agg`. This will necessarily be aligned:

```
df.groupby('id')['name'].agg(['unique', 'nunique'])
```

output:

```
                    unique  nunique
id                                 
a-1         [sfdad, oiuoi]        2
a-2  [oqrwq, ljlsg, uoire]        3
```