# How to create a Pandas Dataframe with group by and a column giving unique count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have seen this answer and what I am looking for is similar I just cannot wrap my head around it. [Group by and count of a pandas dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69919534/group-by-and-count-of-a-pandas-dataframe-column)

I am wanting to count the amount of unique accounts with their respective booking and if they have or have not churned. It is being stored in a Pandas Dataframe.

I have a dataset that looks like:

| Account | Booking | Churn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC inc | New | 1 |
| ABC inc | Upsell | 0 |
| ABC inc | New | 1 |
| Company A | Renew | 0 |
| Company A | New | 1 |
| Company A | Renew | 1 |

I am hoping to get something that looks like

| Account | Booking | Count | Churn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC inc | New | 2 | 1 |
|  | Upsell | 1 | 0 |
| Company A | Renew | 1 | 0 |
|  | New | 1 | 1 |
|  | Renew | 1 | 0 |

I have tried:
df.groupby('ACCOUNT_NAME')['BOOKINGS_TYPE'].agg(['unique','nunique'])

and get this:

| Account Name | Unique | Nunique |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC inc | Upsell | 1 |

I cannot figure out how to get the Churn column added. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may be looking for `df.groupby("Account")["Booking"].value_counts()`, but your input data has 2 rows with "Company A" and "Renew", so I don't understand why that appears twice in the output? What is Churn in the input? How does it result in the Churn output column?

Comment: Or maybe just `df.value_counts()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can group over all the columns and get the aggregate with size.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Account": ["ABC Inc"] * 3 + ["Company A"] * 3,
        "Booking": ["New", "Upsell"] * 3,
        "Churn": [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
    }
)

df.groupby(df.columns.to_list(), as_index=False).size()

# or, as pointed out by Chrysophylaxs
df.value_counts()
```

gives

```
     Account Booking  Churn  size
0    ABC Inc     New      1     2
1    ABC Inc  Upsell      0     1
2  Company A     New      1     1
3  Company A  Upsell      0     1
4  Company A  Upsell      1     1
```

Comment: This is basically equivalent to just calling `df.value_counts()`. Note how OP has Company A, Renew, 0 repeat twice in his output.

Comment: Wow yes, it's getting late here and I had missed both of those. I'll add `df.value_counts()` to my answer, and maybe OP answers about the `Company A, Renew, 0`.